# OutOfMemoryError Even With Enough Memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm reading big files (~ `1 GB`) into byte arrays. Then I'm performing various read operations on them. Unfortunately I'm running into memory problems how it seems.

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent searchPerformed)
    {
        searchButton.setEnabled(false);
        resultsArea.setText("");

        new SwingWorker<String, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
                readFilesAndProcessThem();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void done()
            {
                searchButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
});
```

The application only consumes up to `3.5 GB` of RAM according to `Task Manager` but execution keeps stopping too early. The search button turns grey when the search is started but becomes enabled again shortly after. Why is the `done()` method called already? The code inside the `SwingWorker` does not throw an exception and it didn't complete either.

To fix memory problems, I already added the VM argument `-Xmx` in [`Eclipse`](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) for allowing more memory and set it to something like `10G`. My computer has `10 GB` of free RAM available and the JVM is allowed to use all of it, still my application does not run properly.

Sometimes I see a red line saying `OutOfMemoryError` on the command line when I close the application (not a full exception trace). How can this strange behaviour be explained/fixed?

I'm having the same problems when ran as `Jar` file and the `VM argument` `-Xmx10G`. The results are not 100 % deterministic but it usually stops at the same exact spot. I'm not using an concurrency except for the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: What JRE version are you using (and is it Oracle, OpenJDK, IBM etc)? Depending on which version, the behavior of the default GC algorithm and it's memory model may give some clues. For example, if it's a generational model, it's possible to get OOM in one of the generational areas, which mean you may have to play with tuning the default sizes. All depends on which JDK version you're using. Also, -verbose:gc may give some additional clues

Comment: Are you using 32-bit JRE or 64-bit JRE?  A 32-bit JRE can't use more than around 3.5GB.

Comment: please include the source code of `readFilesAndProcessThem`, as the most probable culprit of the problem

Comment: I'm using Oracle's JDK for Windows 64 bit:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a 32 bit version of the Java Runtime Environment, install the x64 version and it should work.

Comment: It seems to me an answer is a bad place to put what's ultimately a comment

Comment: No, I'm using the 64 bit version